# Can I prevent a pthread from ever being interrupted by the scheduler?

Tags: linux, scheduling, real-time, pthreads

I'm programming an embedded real-time Linux device with a 4 core ARM CPU. There is a requirement for a periodic computation at 10 kHz that should not jitter too much and should never be lost. My POSIX thread can read a HW-provided 10 kHz toggle register in a busy loop and perform the computation whenever the bit is toggled.

In order to keep the `SCHED_RR` scheduler from interrupting the pthread I set the CPU affinity to core 2 exclusively for this thread, and the priority to 99 (maximum). A handful of other threads have CPU affinity set to cores other than 2 and priority 50. But there's still a systemd running and a bunch of other processes.

Is this enough to keep the thread from ever being interrupted by the scheduler? If not, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: no, that is not a guarantee. Why would you do this by busy looping on a hardware toggle instead of using a timer? That seems pretty strange, and also like an explicit invitation for context switches when you don't want them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can timers have a better granularity than the scheduling tick (which is 10ms or so)?

Comment: yes, significantly. (also, your scheduling tick isn't that relevant in this scenario)

Comment: `/proc/timer_list` should "contain" a detailed rundown of all available timers you can use with `timer_create` or, probably more sensible in your use case, `timerfd_create`. Note that "I need to use some component A (be it a timer, a hardware toggle or anything else) to do a computation every 10 ms, for some unnamed component B" screams "You should tell us about what B is, and why you need to do computations every 10 ms, instead of whenever B is ready", because I bet the right solution lies that way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller B is a tracking control loop that needs to be updated at 10kHz (0.1ms!) with a set of values, with time synced to an external 1pps signal which in turn tunes a DPLL. Rocket science; it is going to space, not today, but eventually :-)

Comment: the good thing is that 0.1 ms really isn't very short at all for a modern computer :) So, a DPLL; and you're synthesizing the 10 kHz sample rate of the manipulated Variable ("Stellgröße") in software, based on your CPU's internal clocking? Or are you discipling a VCO with your PPS?

Comment: (by the way, if that PPS is coming from a GPS/GNSS receiver, do take care: civil devices are required to actually not function above a certain speed and altitude, for obvious reasons)

Comment: @MarcusMüller (No GPS). I've tried a 10 kHz timer with timer_create(); it is called 10k times/s, but the jitter is almost over the whole period, with large jitter values less frequent. I have to talk to the control loop folks if that is usable.

Comment: there's different types of timers you can create with `timer_create`, which one did you pick?

Comment: (note that you can probably do nice things like computing your value in time, and programming your hardware timer to DMA it to the right place rather exactly)

Comment: @MarcusMüller CLOCK_REALTIME. And measurements made apparent that I also lose timer handler calls, sometimes just a few, sometimes up to 80 in sequence. It looks like another process may be scheduled. (I can't pre-compute values, as they are read from ADCs at that moment, processed, then written to DACs.)

Comment: Don't use CLOCK_REALTIME for this! That's the one that is the hardest and most jittery to query.

Comment: anyways, this 100% sounds like you actually do have a hardware timer device that should control your ADC conversion, and you should work off the interrupts that triggers, and not a software timer of any kind.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Which other clock would allow a fixed 10kHz wall clock call frequency?

Comment: you'd want MONOTONIC_CLOCK (can't remember whether `timer_create` supports CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW), usually. This has the distinct advantage that things like your computer doing NTP-based "jumpy" clock corrections doesn't interfere with your 0.1 ms timer, and it might also mean that a few more things can work without actually switching context. What jitter distribution do you see, how do you measure that? I remember seeing benchmark where the RMS jitter was ~ 0.1µs, so three orders of magnitude lower), but with a non-zero outlier probability.

Comment: Now, what you'd usually do in this context is being converter-driven, so you wouldn't have a separate timer to do your computations – you have a hardware timer and your ADC programmed on the hardware timer, and an interrupt on completion of a conversion.